# Apache Beam BigqueryIO(Java)io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException:INVALID_ARGUMENT:The primary clustering keys are required to create upsert stream

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using apache beam java to read from one bigquery table and write into another bigquery table using `applyRowMutations()`, but it's not working.

I have created the destination table with the appropriate primary key.

I am using this piece of code.

```
rows.apply(BigQueryIO.applyRowMutations()
                        .to("myproject.testing.test_new")
                        .withJsonSchema(tableSchemaJson)
                        .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STORAGE_API_AT_LEAST_ONCE)
                .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER))
```

But I am observing the following error logs.

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: The primary keys and clustering keys of the table 81082363:testing.test_new are required to create an upsert stream. Entity: projects/myproject/datasets/testing/tables/test_new/streams/_default


java.lang.RuntimeException: Append to stream projects/myproject/datasets/testing/tables/test_new/streams/_default failed with stream doesn't exist
```

I am unable to understand why this issue is occurring.

Comment: Is this tracked by https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/27616?

Comment: yes @XQHu I have raised in github.

Answer (score 0):

The project id and the dataset name should be joined together with colon, not with period. `myproject:testing.test_new` instead of `myproject.testing.test_new`.

The code above should be as follows:

```
rows.apply(BigQueryIO.applyRowMutations()
                        .to("myproject:testing.test_new")
                        .withJsonSchema(tableSchemaJson)
                        .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STORAGE_API_AT_LEAST_ONCE)
                .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER))
```